# Google API "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated use Limit" 403 Error... iOS

Tags: swift, google-api, httprequest, google-calendar-api, alamofire

I am a complete beginner to both iOS dev and working with Google's APIs. I'm learning both of them simultaneously so I apologize if this is a newbie question.

**The Parsing Error has been "repealed & replaced" with a new API error below**

I am trying to write an app that will tell me, that at the time of API request, whether the calendar is in the middle of an event or not.

I tried using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42411188/4330767) posted on a similar question.

<strike>My code looks like this now:</strike> (LOOK AT BOTTOM FOR UPDATES)

```
let json = "{ \"timeMin\": \(currentDate), \"timeMax\": \(currentDate)}"
urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy"


let url = URL(string: urlString)!
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = jsonData

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
    (response) in
    print (response)
    }
```

<strike>And i get the following output:</strike> **(Note: This is fixed by specifying in the json parameter which calendar to retrieve info from)**

```
SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 400;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                message = "Parse Error";
                reason = parseError;
            }
        );
        message = "Parse Error";
    };
}
```

I am unsure how to proceed from here- also, is making a freebusy POST request even the best way to go about solving my problem?

---

**UPDATE:**

So I recognized that in my body parameter, I was not specifying which calendar to request information from: I made the following adjustments:

```
    var body : Parameters  = [
    "timeMin": dateString,
    "timeMax": dateString,
    "items": [
        [
            "id": CALENDAR_ID
        ]]
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {
            (response) in
                print(response)
    }
}
```

However, now I get the following error:

```
SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 403;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = usageLimits;
                extendedHelp = "https://code.google.com/apis/console";
                message = "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.";
                reason = dailyLimitExceededUnreg;
            }
        );
        message = "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured both problems out:

**FIRST- PARSE ERROR**

This error, in the context of freebusy came from my POST parameter *not* specifying which calendars to retrieve information from

**THE SOLUTION:** (crucial part is bolded)

```
var body : Parameters  = [
    "timeMin": dateString,
    "timeMax": dateString,
    "items": [                //make sure you have this (plus next 4 lines)
        [
           "id": CALENDAR_ID
        ]
    ]
]
```

**SECOND- UNAUTHENTICATED USAGE LIMIT ERROR**

I solved this with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13901880/4330767).

> In a nutshell, all of the discovery-based APIs require your calls to
>   be identified. The error you're getting is what I usually see when a
>   Google API can't identify your app. You can usually make a handful of
>   unidentified calls, but you'll almost certainly run into the
>   much-lower "unidentified" quota pretty quickly. You can either
>   authenticate with OAuth (which identifies your app) or you can specify
>   an API key (which identifies your app) or you can do both.

**SOLUTION**

I solved this by appending the API key to my URL as follows (don't click):

> *https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy*?keys=PASTEKEYHERE